# In Ruby, why does plugging in a variable assigned to an array index return undefined?

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables

I am learning Ruby and just solved this pyramid problem. For whatever reason, I tried to change `twoD[0]` to the variable `twoDidx` (see third line).

However, when I try replacing `while twoD[0].length != 1` with `while twoDidx.length != 1`, I get "undefined." What am I not understanding about how variables work? Thanks.

```
def pyramid_sum(base)
  twoD = [base] 
  twoDidx = twoD[0]

  while twoD[0].length != 1
    arr = twoD[0].map.with_index do |num, idx| 
      if idx != twoD[0].length - 1
        num + twoD[0][idx + 1]
      end
    end
    arr = arr.compact
    twoD.unshift(arr)
  end

  return twoD
end

print pyramid_sum([1, 4, 6]) #=> [[15], [5, 10], [1, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a big difference between `twoDidx` and `twoD[0]`. `twoDidx` is a reference to a first element of `twoD` **at the time you made an assignment** while `twoD[0]` is the reference to the first element of `twoD` array at the time of execution.

To make it more obvious:

```
array = [1]
first = array[0] # Here you just assign 1 to the variable
array = [100]

first #=> 1
array[0] #=> 100
```